# how to make navbar and list in the same line with bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I tried a lot about this problem and I didn't figure out why and the list was not in the same line

here is my code
I tried using `display: inline-block;`
and `padding: 0` and still doesn't solve the problem

```css
/* added by editor for demonstration purpose */
body {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Body -->
<section id="title">

  <!-- Nav Bar -->

  <div class="continer-fluid">

    <nav class="navbar1 navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark ">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">TinDog</a>

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-contactrols="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Title -->

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h1 class="h11">Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg DB"><i class="fab fa-apple"></i> Download</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg DB"><i class="fab fa-google-play"></i> Download</button>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <img class="images" margin='right' src="images/iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[image: here is a picture of my problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this CSS.

```
.continer-fluid .navbar1{
   display: flex;
}
```

Comment: thanks dude its work finally , can you give me brief explanation

Comment: just flex did the work!

Comment: welcome bro...!
You have two-element inside the ".navbar1" div. one is "a" and another is a div with id "navbarSupportedContent". Both of these elements must occupy their own space and so that "a" appears first and then the div. In this situation display: flex allows both of them as responsive elements within a container to be automatically arranged depending upon screen size.